# AsyncTask onPostExecute not called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, widget

I have a simple widget with `TextView`'s. One `TextView` should display information obtained from a webpage, and I'm using  this to achieve it:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getString(R.string.srv_dwn);
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        widgetText1 = result;
    }
}
```

The `DownloadWebpageTask` is called from an activity, like this:

```
    DownloadWebpageTask downloadWebpageTask = new DownloadWebpageTask();
    Context context = this;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_appwidget);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
    {
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widgettext1, View.VISIBLE);
        netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        widgetText2 = netInfo.getTypeName();

        downloadWebpageTask.execute("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/");

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext1, widgetText1);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext2, widgetText2);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
    else
    {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext1, widgetText1);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widgettext1, View.GONE);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext2, getString(R.string.tbl_no_connection));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
```

This variable is defined in my `Activity` class and should display the result of `AsyncTask` but does not.

```
public String widgetText1 = "initialtext";
```

Step-by-step debugging shows that `onPostExecute` is never called and the text in the `TextView` is still 'initialtext'.

Second `TextView` updates as required since it doesn't involve an `AsyncTask`.

Similar code including `DownloadWebpageTask` works fine in my main activity, though.

Comment: I'd bet doInBackGround is not getting called.  or it has an exception and returns the initstring.

Comment: If there is an exception it returns a specific string other than 'initialtext', as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to a `Service` instead of an `Activity`, but I think the solution can be impleneted in both cases.

I've created a method in the Service class:

```
public void setIPWidget(String result)
{
    Context context = this;
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_appwidget);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext1, result);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

And in onPostExecute I simply call that method with the result obtained:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        setIPWidget(result);
    }
```

Simplier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is updating a `String` variable. You should use the `setText` method of `EditText` for updating purposes. So in `onPostExecute` do something like the following:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    yourEditText.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Updating a string value and using it later in RemoteViews to update the actual TextView. So you are saying that it is not possible to change a variable in onPostExecure() ?

Comment: Oh okay I see. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. The point of using `onPostExecute` is to update your UI, since `onPostExecute` itself runs on the UI Thread. So why not just update the `EditText` directly?

Comment: I was experiencing problems updating the widget TextViews (like they were not 'visible') so I ended up using an extra varialbe (widgetText1) which was then passed to remoteViews. I'll try to use EditText then.

Comment: I can't see that and no one else has seen your Strings file here either.

Comment: 'Initial text' is just a stub I'm using to check if the code works or not. And the  strings like string.srv_dwn are actually 'Server down'. Nothing complicated here.

Answer (score 0):

execute() method from an AsyncTask runs in the background, so when you call it, the code in your activity continues executing, because there is no way to know how long it will take the execute() method to complete:

```
downloadWebpageTask.execute("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/");

remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext1, widgetText1);
```

So, the second line is executing before onPostExcute() is called, at that point, wigetText1 has still "initialtext" value.

You should update the widget directly (As @Willis said) from onPostExecute() method, it guarantees that it will be updated after the request to the page is done.

If you need to make visible the TextView or anything, do it in onPostExecute() method.

But actually, in order to update your widgets in the main activity, they have to be visible to your AsyncTask, declaring it as an inner class into your Activity class, as follows:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

//Declare the TextView as a instance variable in your activity
public TextView widgetText1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
       //Find your widget in the layout to avoid NullPointerException    when the AsynTask try to update it.
       widgetText1 = findViewById(R.id.some_id);
    }

//Inner class myTask
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //some code
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           widgetText1.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that this way, you have to create a new AsynTask for every activity you want to make a web page request, but here is a reference about how to create a reusable AsyncTask.

[Extracting out your AsyncTasks into separate classes makes your code cleaner](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/extracting-out-your-asynctasks-into-separate-classes-makes-your-code-cleaner/)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{<...>.WidgetUpdateAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I'll just try using a Service instead of an activity, it doesn't want to work, with 1 error or another.